# C Struct syntax question

Tags: c, linux, syntax, struct, kernel

This question appeared when I recently opened a rather old driver for my raid device. To be able to compile the driver for a Linux system, I started to investigate on all those errors I got on output. And I came across this kind of syntax used in the driver sources:

```
struct file_operations t3_fops = {
        owner:                  THIS_MODULE,
        ioctl:                  ft_ioctl,
        fasync:                 ft_fasync,
        open:                   ft_open,
        release:                ft_release
};
```

So guys, could you help me to understand what does ":" mean? Is this C syntax at all? I know there is a bit field definition, but this looks rather different to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This syntax for initializing structure members is called a [designated initializer](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits). The `:` is older GCC-specific syntax.  This is documented in the [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits).

Comment: I believe this is the right answer :-) Still I have a question on it: why there isn't a way to assign **default values** to a struct in C? If we can use the syntax `:` in the definition of a struct, it would be very convenient.

Answer (score 6):

This is C99 struct initialization syntax. `owner`, `ioctl`, etc, are names of fields in the struct, and `THIS_MODULE`, `ft_ioctl`, etc, are the values. This is effectively doing the following, except at compile time:

```
struct file_operations t3_fops;
t3_fops.owner = THIS_MODULE;
t3_fops.ioctl = ft_ioctl;
...
```

The new syntax is nice, because it makes the initialization work regardless of the order of the struct fields.

Comment: In standard **6.7.8 Initialization**, I cannot see the ':' syntax so I think it's an extension of gcc. Or I miss the contents on it? Could you please point out where the standard mentions the struct initialization syntax ':'? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I remembered the wrong syntax. Indeed the colon is a gcc extension, `[owner] THIS_MODULE` is the standard syntax. (I think. I don't have access to my copy of the standard right now.)